# Navegación y pasar datos entre páginas

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

Deseo pasar información de una página a otra, windows phone 8.1 y uso este método para navegar en la página origen:

```
 navigation nav = new navigation();
            {
                nav.name = tb1.Text;
                nav.value = int.Parse(tb3.Text);
            };
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(pagina1),nav);
```

En la página de destino:

```
var nav = (navigation)e.Parameter;

            mytext1.Text = nav.name;
            mytext2.Text = nav.value.ToString();
            text2.Text = nave.value2.ToString();
```

Y ésta es la clase de navegación:

```
 public class navigation
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
}
```

Cuando intento pasarle la información a mas de una página llamando los objetos anteriores tengo esta excepción:

> System.InvalidCastException

no sé cómo continuar.

Comment: cuando mencionas la pagina de destino, en que evento o metodos recibes los parametros? en realidad lo pregunto para saber de donde sale "e"

Comment: pagina fuente:
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           pagina fuente y los parametrs;
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(pagina1),nav);
        }
pagina destino

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            
}cuando intento pasar los parametros de la segunda pagina ahi encuentro el error, como si solo puediera hacerlo con la primera pagina

Answer (score 1):

En principio pareceria estar correcto lo que planteas, veo ejemplos que planteas lo mismo que describes

[Tip: Passing Multiple Parameters to a New Page in Windows Store Apps – Boredom Challenge Day 8](https://eren.ws/2013/10/12/tip-passing-multiple-parameters-to-a-new-page-in-windows-store-apps-boredom-challenge-day-8/)

[Passing Data from Page to Page for Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946575/passing-data-from-page-to-page-for-windows-phone-8-1)

pero teniendo en cuenta que por falla, podrias evaluar el uso del `NavigationService.Navigate()`

[How to perform page navigation on Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[Navigation based WPF applications](http://www.win2wpf.com/WPFNavigation.aspx)

podrias ver de enviar el dato desde la url

```
private void passParam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=" + textBox1.Text, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

y lo recibes

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string msg = "";

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))

            textBlock1.Text = msg;


}
```

Comment: estoy trabajando con windows phone 8.1, el navigation service no esta hablitado, pues tengo entendido que funciona para windows phone 7, 7.5 y 8, no para 8.1 a mi entender

Comment: @CesarG.Rivas si es verdad analizando el tema entiendo lo mismo para Phone 8.1 se implementa como lo mencionas con el Frame.Navigate, si asignas un datos simple, del tipo string o numerico lo recibes de forma correcta?

Comment: si, pero el problema me aparece cuando intento pasar los datos de mas de una pagina

Comment: @CesarG.Rivas como es eso de "mas de una pagina" ? estas navegando de una pagina a otra, no hay mas de una son solo dos las que intervienen en la accion de navegar

Comment: dos paginas diferentes le pasan datos a una tercera, en una pagina paso nombre y valor numerico, otra pagina solo pasa valores, por eso solo 3